# Getting Facebook Profile Pic in tableView Cell's ImageView

Tags: iphone, facebook, uitableview, xcode4.2

i have created an application in facebook required for my iphone application.
i am able to login to facebook account and i can allow that application into my application.
am  able to get profile pic url of loggedIn user.

**EDIT**
my problem is 
i need to convert that url to image type and need to display in tableview cell.
can anyone tell me regarding this. 
please help me.
thanks alot for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do a request like this:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture" andDelegate:self];
```

and then:

```
(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
}
```

Comment: hai @Sebrassi. can u please tell where to call [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture" andDelegate:self]; method. actually i have written both u mentioned above.but i am not getting the image. may be i am calling wrong place. help me pls.

Comment: you should take a look at the new Facebook SDK for iOS: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/personalize/

Comment: thanks @Sebrassi it helps for me . Can you please help me in displaying that profile pic in tableview cell's imageview. please help me any one in this.