# Displaying FB Profile Pic of loggedIn User in UITableView Cell

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, uitableview, uiimage

I am a new one to facebook integration. After I've gone through so many tutorials I've understood something from facebook SDK.

Please help me regarding this.

```
- (void)apiGraphMe
{
 currentAPICall = kAPIGraphMe;
 AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"name,picture",  @"fields",
                               nil];
 [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
{
NSLog(@"result is------------%@",result);
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    NSLog(@"id is: %@", [result objectForKey:@"id"]); 
    NSString *idValue = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
}
}
```

In above code I am getting URL of loggedIn user profile pic. My wish is to display that url image into tableView cell.

I think directly passing that url image to tableview cell's imageview is not correct way. If
we pass the id of the user based on that we can get profile pic. Because it reduces the complexity if other user logged in.

Hope you understand the problem and context. Kindly excuse me if any grammer or english language mistakes are there.

Thanks alot for any help and replies in advance.

Comment: Please help me anybody regarding this....:):)

Comment: Don't ask same kind of question multiple times,just update the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093323/getting-facebook-profile-pic-in-tableview-cells-imageview

Comment: am updated my question @Born Survivior.but no one is responding to that question.thats why i asked newly.sorry for my mistake. a

Comment: Yeah,but according to previos link,you are getting the image,so why don't you use that image directly?

Comment: That's what I am answering to your question,you have received image,in that previous question,so why don't you display in cell using ,`cell.imageView.image`

Comment: i dont know how to display that url type image data into cell.imageView.image. please help me @Born Survivior.

Comment: is your name is Ravi DIXIt.just for confirmation i have asked this.please dont mine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15899/discussion-between-born-survivor-and-iphone-newbie)

Answer (score 4):

here are the steps to show user/friends profile image in tableview

- you already have user/friends ids
- declare IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *userProfileImage; // make sure you import FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h
- in your IB/Storeyboard tableview cell, drag a UIView (width 36, height 36)
- change the class of this uiview (in identity inspector to FBProfilePictureView)
- connect your iboutlet above to this FBProfilePictureView
- in cellForRowAtIndexPath, assign image as below
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
       cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
  {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FriendsCell";

  FriendsCell *cell = (FriendsCell*)[tableView 
                                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  cell.userProfileImage.profileID = objUD.userID;
  return cell;
  }

Note: I am assuming you have a custom UITableViewCell class called FriendsCell

In viewDidLoad method, write the below line
    [FBProfilePictureView class];